# How do I restart a process someone else is using

Tags: deployment, process, capistrano

I'm pretty new to ops so please don't mind if use the incorrect terms.

I have a program that runs on another box. I need to restart the program after I deploy code to it, via capistrano. I tried sshing into the box to do the restart but it won't work because the program requires a screen/display to run. Is there a way for me to restart the process and tell the process to keep using the screen it is currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you're referring to a UNIX/Linux box with Xorg (X11) going on it.  I am going to also assume you at least one active display (i.e. :0 exists).  Knowing more about the nature of the application (i.e. what it does) would be great.

1. SSH into the box like you did before.  You *may* want to be become root (**su** or **sudo bash**- assuming you have bash) or log in as the user (or do **su *username***).
2. execute your script but tell it which display to use by setting the DISPLAY variable.

   ```
   # DISPLAY=:0; /path/to/your/app
   ```

That'd work if you have bash.  Try that out and let us know what happens and/or if you don't have bash.

Good luck

Comment: I was on a raspberry pi. Apparently using sudo did the trick for me. I'm not sure why the permissions mattered. Any idea?